# Grid for 2x2 table in Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, graphics

I am new to WPF. I want to draw a simple 2 rows by 2 columns table inside a Canvas. Can I use a 2x2 Grid to do this? One obvious problem is that the Grid stays 'invisible' in the Canvas, probably because it is meant to hold other visual controls ( instead of being visible itself, which is what I want). If Grid is a bad idea for this 2x2 table, please advise the correct method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid panel would be a quick way to draw this. In order to give the visual appearance of a grid I would recommend putting a border inside each one of the cells and setting its borderthickness and borderbrush.

There are many other ways to accomplish this but for something this simple the above method should suffice.